# Wordpress Site block Joomla URLs using hatches

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site on SiteGround and have hundreds of attempts entering looking for http://example.com/?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=user&id=93265

The old site used Joomla and it appears that bots still have the site on their list.

Please let me know if there is a way to prevent these requests from causing an "execution" of index.php as this has a 20,000 execution daily limit on Siteground shared host. Passing the limit causes the site to be disabled.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Found this on http://botcrawl.com/how-to-block-incoming-traffic-backlinks-attempted-site-hijacks-and-multiple-urls-in-the-htaccess-file/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_k2

RewriteRule ^ - [F]

It appears to working. I'll write back if not.